GitHub Actions SSH Deployment Error to Google Cloud VM
I'm encountering an error while deploying to my Google Cloud VM using GitHub Actions and SSH. Previously, the workflow was working flawlessly, but now it's failing during deployment.
Details:
Workflow configuration:
name: Deploy to Remote Machine

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Check SERVER_IP
        run: |
          echo "Server IP: ${{secrets.SERVER_IP}}"
      - name: Install SSH key
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ssh-keyscan -t rsa  ${{secrets.SERVER_IP}} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: Deploy to Google Cloud VM
        run: |
          ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ${{secrets.SSH_USERNAME}}@${{secrets.SERVER_IP}} '
            sudo ./deploy_file.sh
          '


Use code with caution.
Error message:
Install SSH key
Run mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  echo "***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***
  ***" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ssh-keyscan -t rsa  *** >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

Additional context:
I can successfully connect to the VM manually using the same SSH key. However, the connection seems slower during the GitHub Actions workflow.
I've verified the following:
The SERVER_IP, SSH_USERNAME, and private key content are correct in GitHub secrets.
Network connectivity exists between the runner and the VM. (List any other troubleshooting steps you've already tried)
Question:
What could be causing this deployment error in GitHub Actions?
Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can take to identify the root cause?
Manual SSH login is slow too, suggesting a network issue, not workflow. I'm stuck - any tips to troubleshoot the slow connection and workflow error?
Edit 1
I think this error is due to high cpu utilization  CPU Utilization
